# JavaFX ProgressBar Value doesn't work

Tags: progress-bar, javafx-2, javafx

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0.0);
pb.setProgress(1.0 - (1.0 / ((1.0 * 60) / 15000)));
```

I want progress bar show 60min state, but when left 15000min not really showing state.

Comment: Where do you have your progress bar and where do you update the progress bar? Can you provide a full example of your desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.0 - (1.0 / ((1.0 * 60) / 15000))` resolves to -249.0. A negative number indicates that you want to show indeterminate progress, which is why the progress bar will not show an actual value. Set the progress to a positive number between 0.0 and 1.0, or rather adapt your math accodingly.